# Does Python copy value or reference upon object instantiation?

Tags: python, object, language-design, instantiation

A simple question, perhaps, but I can't quite phrase my Google query to find the answer here. I've had the habit of making copies of objects when I pass them into object constructors, like so:

```
...
def __init__(self, name):
    self._name = name[:]
...
```

However, when I ran the following test code, it appears to not be necessary, that Python is making deep copies of the object values upon object instantiation:

```
>>> class Candy(object):
...     def __init__(self, flavor):
...             self.flavor = flavor
...
>>> flav = "cherry"
>>> a = Candy(flav)
>>> a
<__main__.Candy object at 0x00CA4670>
>>> a.flavor
'cherry'
>>> flav += ' and grape'
>>> flav
'cherry and grape'
>>> a.flavor
'cherry'
```

So, what's the real story here? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Olivier for his great answer. The following code documents a better example that Python does copy by reference:

```
>>> flav = ['a','b']
>>> a = Candy(flav)
>>> a.flavor
['a', 'b']
>>> flav[1] = 'c'
>>> flav
['a', 'c']
>>> a.flavor
['a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is because strings are **immutable**.

The operator `+=`, rather confusingly, actually *reassigns* the variable it is applied to, if the object is immutable:

```
s = 'a'
ids = id(s)
s += 'b'
ids == id(s) # False, because s was reassigned to a new object
```

So, in your case, in the beginning, both `flav` and `a.flavor` point to the same string object:

```
flav --------\
               'cherry'
a.flavor ----/
```

But when you write `flav += 'and grape'` the variable `flav` gets **reassigned** to a new string object:

```
flav --------> 'cherry and grape'
a.flavor ----> 'cherry' # <-- that string object never changes
```

It is confusing, because usually, when you call an operator on a variable, it doesn't change the variable. But just in the case of an immutable object, it does reassign the variable.

So the final answer to your question is, yes, it makes sense to copy the objects upon instantiation, especially if you are expecting a mutable object (which is often the case). It the object was immutable, it will not harm to copy it anyway.

Comment: To clarify, `self.flavor = flavor` does copy by reference, but because strings are immutable the referenced object can not be changed. Therefore, `flav += ' and grape` actually creates a new string object and makes `flav` reference it.

Comment: @taleinat: thanks, I updated the answer, hoping it doesn't get to confusing.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. I guess then, I'm still left wondering if copying objects upon instantiation is a good idea, since I don't see many places where it's done. Any suggestions there?

Comment: @daveslab: if you still have questions, why accept this answer?

Comment: @S.Lott because it is out of the scope of the question I stated above, which was answered by @Olivier. The real criticism you could've brought is that I should've opened a new question about Python style, but I was hoping for just brief words of advice and didn't want to go through all the trouble. So be it.

Comment: @daveslab:  "the real criticism?"  I'm not criticizing.  I'm asking.  You have further questions, yet you accepted the answer.  That is a simple contradiction which I do not understand.  I'm asking.  "if you still have questions, why accept this answer?"

Answer (score 1):

> it appears to not be necessary

Appears?  Your question is *entirely* about design and meaning.  This is not a preference or habit question.

Does the class contract include the ability modify a mutable argument?  If so, do NOT make a copy.

Does the class contract assert that a mutable argument will not be modified?  If so, you MUST make a copy.

Your questions is answered *entirely* by the contract definition for the class.

Comment: I see the area of your confusion. I should've had a sentence at the top saying that my goal was to ensure that the variables passed to `__init__` were copied by value, not by reference into the object. What I meant by `It appears to not be necessary` is that it seemed that I didn't need to use my copying methods because Python was doing it anyway. I was incorrect.

Comment: @daveslab: Don't comment.  Fix the question.  Please **update** the question to clearly state what your objective actually is.  Other people read these questions trying to learn Python and good program design.  Please fix the question to be perfectly clear.